# Boost: How to locate the position of the iterator inside a huge text file?

Tags: regex, boost, text, iterator

I'm working in a program that uses boost::regex to match some patterns inside a huge text file (greater than 200 MB). The matches are working fine, but to build the output file I need to order the matches (just 2, but over all the text) in the sequence they are found in the text.
Well, when in debug mode, during the cout procedure I can see inside the iterator **it1** an **m_base** attribute that shows an address that is increased each step of the loop and I think this m_base address is the address of the matched pattern in the text, but I could not certify it and I could not find a way to access this attribute to store the address.
I don't know if there is any way to retrieve the address of each matched pattern in the text, but I really need to get this information.

```
#define FILENAME "File.txt"
int main() { 

    int length;     
    char * cMainBuf;
    ifstream is;
    is.open (FILENAME, ios::binary );

    is.seekg(0, ios::end);
    length = is.tellg();
    is.seekg (0, ios::beg);

    cMainBuf = new char[length+1];
    memset(cMainBuf, '\0',length+1);

    is.read(cMainBuf,length);
    is.close();
    string str=cMainBuf;
    regex reg("^(\\d{1,3}\\s[A-F]{99})");
    regex rReg(reg);
    int const sub_matches[] = { 1 };
    boost::sregex_token_iterator it1(str.begin() ,str.end() ,rReg ,sub_matches ), it2; 
    while(it1!=it2) 
    { 
        cout<<"#"<<sz++<<"- "<< *(it1++) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

@sln
Hi sln,
I'll answer your questions:
1. I removed all code that is not part of this issue, so some libraries remaining there;
2. Same as 1;
3. Because the file is not a simple text file in fact, it can have any symbol and it may affect the reading procedure, as I could realize in the past;
4. Zero buffer was necessary during the tests period, since I could not store more than 1MB in the buffer;
5. the iterator doesn't allo to use char* to set the beggining and the end of the file, so was necessary to change it to string;
6. The incoming RegEx will not be declared static, this is just a draft to show the problem and the anchor act to find the line start, not only the string start;
7. sub_matches was part of the test to see where the iterator was for regex with 2 or more groups inside it;
8. sz is just a counter;
9. There is no cast possible from const std::_String_const_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> to long.

In fact all the code works fine, I can identify any pattern inside the text, but what I really need to know is the memory address of each matched pattern (in this case, the address of the iterator for each iteration). I could realize that m_base has this address, but I could not retrieve this address until this moment.
Ill continue the analysis, if I find any solution for this problem I  post it here.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** @Tchesko, I am deleting my original answer. I've loaded the boost::regex and tried it out with a regex_search(). Its not the itr1 method like you are doing but, I think it comes down to just getting the results from the boost::smatch class, which is really boost::match_results().

It has member functions to get the position and length of the match and sub-matches. So, its really all you need to find the offset into your big string. The reason you can't get to m_base is that it is a private member variable.

Use the methods position() and length(). See the sample below... which I ran, debugged and tested. I'm getting back up to speed with VS-2005 again. But, boost does seem a little quirky. If I am going to use it, I want it to do Unicode, and than means I have to compile ICU. The boost binarys I'm using is downloaded 1.44. The latest is 1.46.1 so I might build it with vc++ 8 after I asess it viability with ICU.

Hey, let me know how it turns out. Good luck!

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp> 
#include <locale> 
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
  std::locale::global(std::locale("German")); 
  std::string s = "  Boris  Schäling   "; 
  boost::regex expr("(\\w+)\\s*(\\w+)"); 
  boost::smatch what; 
  if (boost::regex_search(s, what, expr)) 
  { 
      // These are from boost::match_results() class ..
      int Smpos0 = what.position();
      int Smlen0 = what.length();
      int Smpos1 = what.position(1);
      int Smlen1 = what.length(1);
      int Smpos2 = what.position(2);
      int Smlen2 = what.length(2);

      printf ("Match Results\n--------------\n");
      printf ("match  start/end  = %d - %d,  length = %d\n", Smpos0, Smpos0 + Smlen0,  Smlen0);
      std::cout << "  '" << what[0] << "'\n" << std::endl; 
      printf ("group1 start/end  = %d - %d,  length = %d\n", Smpos1, Smpos1 + Smlen1, Smlen1);
      std::cout << "  '" << what[1] << "'\n" << std::endl; 
      printf ("group2 start/end  = %d - %d,  length = %d\n", Smpos2, Smpos2 + Smlen2, Smlen2);
      std::cout << "  '" << what[2] << "'\n" << std::endl;

/*
    This is the hard way, still m_base is a private member variable.
    Without m_base, you can't get the root address of the buffer.

    long Match_start = (long)(what[0].first._Myptr);
    long Match_end   = (long)(what[0].second._Myptr);
    long Grp1_start  = (long)(what[1].first._Myptr);
    long Grp1_end    = (long)(what[1].second._Myptr);
*/
  } 
} 

/* Output:
Match Results
--------------
match  start/end  = 2 - 17,  length = 15
  'Boris  Schäling'

group1 start/end  = 2 - 7,  length = 5
  'Boris'

group2 start/end  = 9 - 17,  length = 8
  'Schäling'
*/
```

Comment: I added some comments related to your suggestions in my question (edited below the code snippet).

Comment: Good news, finally I could identify the address in the buffer by using &(*it1->first), now it is working fine.